# XMLHttpRequest PHP Chats

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to create a system to display messages on 2 or more separate chats( with different messages stored in a db) on the same page. The chats each have ids to differentiate them and I have created a function to go through each chat in use and print the approprite messages for them but only 1 chat gets the messages.
The Code:
The HTML

```
<div class="full_wrap">
   <div class="force-overflow"></div>
   <div id="Sidenav" class="side">

      <h2>Chat Settings & Info</h2>

      <a id="closebtn" href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

      <div class="authr">

         <a>
            <div class="authr_img"></div>​
         </a>

         <form action="mypage.php" method="post">
            <div class="authr_name">
               <button value="<?php echo $chat_authr ?>" name="userlink" class="subm_as_text"><?php echo $chat_authr;  ?></button>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>

      <div class="chat_info">

         <div class="chat_descy">

            <h2>Chat Description</h2>
            <div class="descc">
               <h3><?php echo $chat_description; ?></h3>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="chat_fol"><h2>Chat users: <?php echo $num_users; ?></h2></div>

         <div class="chat_back">
            <h2> Change Chat Wallpaper</h2>

            <form method="post" action="picture.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <input type="file" id="upload" class="custom-file-input" name="chat_wall">
               <input type="submit" class="chat_wall_subm" value="Change"/>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>

      <form method="post" action="chat.php" >
         <!--<input type="submit" class="chat_leave" name="" value="Leave Chat">-->

         <button class="chat_leave" name="chat_leave" value="<?php echo $chat_index; ?>" >Leave Chat</button>
      </form>
   </div>


   <div class="mnav">
      <span onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
      <i class="material-icons" id="chat_un_small" onclick="chat_un_small()">arrow_upward</i>
      <h1><?php echo $chat_title ?></h1>

   </div>


   <!--one ting-->
   <div class="conceal_wrapper">
      <div class="msgs" id="5e2dbe2be3b5927c588509edb1c46f7d">
      </div>

      <form method="post" id="form_5e2dbe2be3b5927c588509edb1c46f7d" class="comform">
         <div class="wcom" >
            <input maxlength="140" type = "text" id="5e2dbe2be3b5927c588509edb1c46f7d"  class="comin" placeholder="My message..." name="sendmsg" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off"/>
            <input class="hidden_index" type="text" value="5e2dbe2be3b5927c588509edb1c46f7d" name="chat_index"/>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>

   <div class="chat_enlarge">
      <div class="chat_enlarge_full" onmouseover="chat_action(this)" onmouseout="chat_action_negative(this)" onclick="chat_enlarge_full()"></div>
      <div class="chat_enlarge_standard"  onmouseover="chat_action(this)" onmouseout="chat_action_negative(this)" onclick="chat_enlarge_standard()"></div>
      <div class="chat_enlarge_small"  onmouseover="chat_action(this)" onmouseout="chat_action_negative(this)" onclick="chat_enlarge_small()"></div>
   </div>

</div>



<div class="full_wrap">
   <div class="force-overflow"></div>
   <div id="Sidenav" class="side">

      <h2>Chat Settings & Info</h2>

      <a id="closebtn" href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

      <div class="authr">

         <a>
            <div class="authr_img"></div>​
         </a>

         <form action="mypage.php" method="post">
            <div class="authr_name">
               <button value="<?php echo $chat_authr ?>" name="userlink" class="subm_as_text"><?php echo $chat_authr;  ?></button>
            </div>
         </form>

      </div>


      <div class="chat_info">
         <div class="chat_descy">
            <h2>Chat Description</h2>
            <div class="descc">
               <h3><?php echo $chat_description; ?></h3>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="chat_fol"><h2>Chat users: <?php echo $num_users; ?></h2></div>

         <div class="chat_back">
            <h2> Change Chat Wallpaper</h2>

            <form method="post" action="picture.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <input type="file" id="upload" class="custom-file-input" name="chat_wall">
               <input type="submit" class="chat_wall_subm" value="Change"/>
            </form>
         </div>

      </div>

      <form method="post" action="chat.php" >
         <!--<input type="submit" class="chat_leave" name="" value="Leave Chat">-->

         <button class="chat_leave" name="chat_leave" value="<?php echo $chat_index; ?>" >Leave Chat</button>
      </form>
   </div>


   <div class="mnav">
      <span onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
      <i class="material-icons" id="chat_un_small" onclick="chat_un_small()">arrow_upward</i>
      <h1><?php echo $chat_title ?></h1>

   </div>


   <!--one ting-->
   <div class="conceal_wrapper">
      <div class="msgs" id="9503e253936e716f18d9c57b4f97d618">


      </div>



      <form method="post" id="form_9503e253936e716f18d9c57b4f97d618" class="comform">
         <div class="wcom" >
            <input maxlength="140" type = "text" id="9503e253936e716f18d9c57b4f97d618"  class="comin" placeholder="My message..." name="sendmsg" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off"/>
            <input class="hidden_index" type="text" value="9503e253936e716f18d9c57b4f97d618" name="chat_index"/>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>

   <div class="chat_enlarge">
      <div class="chat_enlarge_full" onmouseover="chat_action(this)" onmouseout="chat_action_negative(this)" onclick="chat_enlarge_full()"></div>
      <div class="chat_enlarge_standard"  onmouseover="chat_action(this)" onmouseout="chat_action_negative(this)" onclick="chat_enlarge_standard()"></div>
      <div class="chat_enlarge_small"  onmouseover="chat_action(this)" onmouseout="chat_action_negative(this)" onclick="chat_enlarge_small()"></div>
   </div>

</div>
```

So there are 2 chats separated by the full_wrap class. The msgs have different id for the chat index stored unique for each chat in the db

The Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  chat_receivemsgs();
});


function chat_receivemsgs(){
  var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('msgs');
  if(cusid_ele.length == 0) {
    console.log("hi");
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) {
      var item = cusid_ele[i];
      var item_id = item.id;
      console.log(cusid_ele.length);

      for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) {
        var item = cusid_ele[i];
        var item_id = item.id;
        console.log(item_id);

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log("yes");
            console.log(item_id);
            //  document.getElementById(item_id).innerHTML = this.responseText;
            $("#"+item_id).html(this.responseText);
          }else{
            console.log("no");
            console.log(item_id);
          }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","receivemsg.php?q="+item_id,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

receivemsgs.php just selects all messages in the messages table with the index of the index given by item_id. The problem is as stated that only the chat with 9503e253936e716f18d9c57b4f97d618 id receives the messages.

I heard that the requests repeat 4 times but I am not an expert in this field. By using the console, I understood that it ignores the first chat and only generates the messages for 9503e253936e716f18d9c57b4f97d618.

Any help would appreciate.
Also if there is a better way to control more than one chat on the same page, I wold love to know how to.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in how you're using XMLHttpRequest.

See this snippet:

```js
function Obj() {
}

Obj.prototype = {
 callFunc: function() {
  setTimeout(this.func, 1000);
 }
};


function test() {
 var ids = ['id1', 'id2'];

 for (var i = 0 ; i < 2 ; ++i) {
  var id = ids[i];
  var obj = new Obj();

  obj.func = function() {
   console.log(id);
  };

  obj.callFunc();
 }
}

test();
```

As you can see, the code prints "id2" twice to the console. That's similar to your problem.

What happens is that, in `obj.func` (in your code, that's `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange`), the `id` variable (respectively `item_id`) comes from the outer function. Its value when `obj.func` is assigned is not "saved". When the function finally gets executed, it will use the last known value for that variable.

So here's what happens:

- `i = 0`
- `id = ids[0] = 'id1'`
- a new Obj is created (let's call it `obj1`) and assigned to `obj`
- `obj1.func` is created
- `obj1.callFunc` is called, it programs `obj1.func` to be called later
- `i = 1`
- `id = ids[1] = 'id2'`
- a new Obj is created (let's call it `obj2`) and assigned to `obj`
- `obj2.func` is created
- `obj2.callFunc` is called, it programs `obj2.func` to be called later
- `obj1.func` gets called, it prints the last value of `id`, that is "id2"
- `obj2.func` gets called, it prints the last value of `id`, that is "id2"

There are a few ways around that behavior. You could retrieve `item_id` from PHP's output somehow. You could set `item_id` to a member of `xmlhttp` and use that in your function (`xmlhttp.item_id = item_id;` then inside the function `this.item_id`). Or you could use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/bind). With the latter solution, your code becomes:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(this_item_id) {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log("yes");
    console.log(this_item_id);
    //  document.getElementById(this_item_id).innerHTML = this.responseText;
    $("#"+this_item_id).html(this.responseText);
  }else{
    console.log("no");
    console.log(this_item_id);
  }
}.bind(xmlhttp, item_id);

xmlhttp.open("GET","receivemsg.php?q="+item_id,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

By the way, I don't understand why you're iterating twice on `cusid_ele` (you have two nested loops).

Comment: OMGGGG IT WORKS. THANK YOU SO MUCH. Yeah there was supposed to be only one loop that was a little type. But still thank you.